# Problem loading content with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

Ahoy everyone,

I try to load content into a div using [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/) tutorial. I am using jquery for this.
The problem is that, when i click the link

```
<a href="about.html" class="panel">Profil</a>
```

it loads about.html as a seperate page. I tried it with several scripts, but for some reason it looks like

```
 $("#content").load
```

does not work at all!
I am sure my HTML is valid as i took it nearly 1:1 from the tutorial and only modified the targets.

heres the full javascript;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Check for hash value in URL
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('#nav li a').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
            var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
            $('#container').load(toLoad)
        } 

    $('#nav li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#container').hide('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#container').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#container').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;

    });
});
```

What could be possible reasons of this?

Comment: Your syntax is looking OK at this point so it could perhaps be something else minor that's causing issues.  Are you running Firebug to help debug the ajax communication with the server?  -- http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: the firebug console does not report any bugs (with the default settings)

Comment: Does it work with FF and not IE?

Comment: i tried only on FF 3.5. i assumed that if its not working with FF its not working at all :) i will do some tests tomorrow

Comment: I still think this didn't work for a simple reason... maybe you're using ".htm" for your file names and the script relies on the file name ending with ".html", hence the .attr('href').length-5 in the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright, i got it to work with [another script](http://frinity.blogspot.com/2008/06/load-remote-content-into-div-element.html).

Answer (score 3):

You need to prevent the default action of the link:

```
$("a.loader").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#content").load(/* Your details here */);
});
```

Comment: does not have any effect either, but thanks for the fast reply

Answer (score 0):

Return false. Let jQuery handle stopping the default action:

```
$(".panel").click(function ()
{
    $("#content").load();

    return false;
});
```

Comment: i added the full javascript, and as you can see, return false is included - thanks

Answer (score 0):

alright, the problem seems to be in

```
$('#nav li a').click(function(){
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    alert("Text");
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    alert("Text 2");
    return false;
    });
```

because any alert("text") set in there dont show up. does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I think I see the problem...

From that tutorial page. The index.html, about.html, portfolio.html, contact.html and term.html are all duplicate pages except for the #content portion. So does your about.html contain a `<div id="content">`, or is it just a page you wanted to load into the content area. If it's the latter, then I would change the "#content" to "body", from:

```
var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
```

to

```
var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' body';
```